# How to obtain service object in Junit test?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Springboot project and have a service class:

```
@Service("requestService")
public class RequestServiceImpl implements RequestService {

    @Autowired
    QueryService queryService;

    public RequestServiceImpl() {
    }

    public RequestServiceImpl(QueryService queryService) {
        this.queryServce = queryService;
    }

    @Override
    public Response getResponse(QueryInfo queryInfo) {

        return queryService.queryGraph(queryInfo);
    } 
}
```

In my JUnit test, I want to test this class:

```
public class RequstServiceTest {

      @Mock 
      QueryService queryService;

@Test
public void testRequestInfo() {

     // I can't do this
     RequestService requestService = new 
     RequestServiceImpl(queryService);
     ...
     requestService.getResponse(queryInfo); 
}
```

How to inject an object of ReqeustServiceImpl in my testing environment?

EDIT: after following the suggestion and modified the code as above, I still get a null pointer exception for 'queryService' inside RequestServiceImpl.

> ```
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
> SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
>
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:74)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
>   at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
>   at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
>   at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:226)
>   at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:64)
>   at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1864)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:36)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
>   at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
>   at com.qt.service.LocalServiceTest.doSetup(LocalServiceTest.java:35)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>   at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>   at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>   at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>   at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>   at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>   at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
>   at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor
>   at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.<init>(PowerMockMaker.java:43)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>   at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:49)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:57)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:44)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:21)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:18)
>   at org.mockito.internal.configuration.GlobalConfiguration.tryGetPluginAnnotationEngine(GlobalConfiguration.java:55)
>   at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:68)
>   ... 23 more
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.cglib.proxy.MethodInterceptor
>   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
>   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>   ... 36 more
> ```

Comment: *I can't do this*: yes, you can. What's missing is the QueryService dependency, though, which is one of the reasons why Spring recommends constructor injection rather than field injection. But even with field injection, you can use Mockito's annotations to inject a mock QueryService inside RequestServiceImpl.

Comment: @JBNizet， could you give an example of achieving this? I want to be able to do unit test.

Comment: @JBNizet, please see my modification.

Answer (score 2):

enter code hereThe @Mock annotation just declares the reference one that can be injected by Mockito.  To trigger the actual injection of the mock, add the following to your test method.

```
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
```

See: https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.28/org/mockito/MockitoAnnotations.html#initMocks(java.lang.Object)

As this is a class-level variable, it appears you want to be able to use this mock across test methods, so a good approach is to use an `@Before` method for this.  Methods annotated with `@Before` will be executed before each test method, thus ensuring that each test has a newly initialized version of your mock.

```
@Before
public void doSetup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: Error message: 'this' can't be referenced from a static environment.

Comment: I removed the static from the method, and received "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)"

Comment: Oops.  I should not have put `static`.  I have removed that from my answer.

Comment: As for the IllegalStateException - please post the full stack trace.